# Find path from tuple with most free space

Tags: python

I have a tuple of filesystem paths like so:

```
storage_locations = (
    '/Location/One/',
    '/Location/Two/',
    '/Location/Three/',
)
```

These will likely be located on various disks with differing amounts of free space. I'd like to find the path which has the most free space but I can't figure out how in a way that doesn't seem overly complicated.

I've got this far:

```
def get_free_space(path):
    return shutil.disk_usage(path).free

largest_space = max(map(get_free_space, storage_locations))
```

The information that I want is the path to the location with the largest amount of free space, however, I just have the number of bytes free at that location.

I feel like there must be a way to, on-the-fly, create a dict where each pair contains the path and the amount of space free at that path. Then, using that, find the path for which the free space is the greatest.

But after trying numerous things I can't seem to get very far in working out a nice way to do this, in a few lines or so while still being readable. There must be a 'pythonic' way to do this nicely :)

Comment: you got an excellent answer already. Be aware `max` features a key parameter you can use to specify the criteria for the comparison . e.g. `path_with_largest_space = max(storage_locations, key=get_free_space)`

Comment: I like this better, it seems more Pythonic to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `max` considers each item of a tuple in turn, you can associate free space with path and get them both back.

```
>>> storage_locations = [ '/' ]
>>> max((shutil.disk_usage(path).free, path) for path in storage_locations)
(570431541248, '/')
>>>
```

If you want a dict, you can construct it similarly

```
>>> dict(((path, shutil.disk_usage(path).free) for path in storage_locations))
{'/': 570431426560}
```

Comment: The dict comprehension would be better written as `d = {path: space for path in locations}`.

Comment: I was trying things close to your first example with `max`, but not quite the right thing. This is what I've ended up choosing to do :)